# Why this simple stored procedure isn't working

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

Here is the deal, I am receiving an array from C# and I want to insert it into the following table with only 2 columns which are `@idUser int` and `@idRegion int`.

The stored procedure needs to receive the array and insert it into the table but somehow it isn't working, it tells me that it cannot convert `@idRegion` to an int. I tried to use `CAST` and `CONVERT` to convert it into int but it isn't working.

The `Select From` works ok, but not the insert.

Here is the stored procedure (`@idUser` needs to be the same for all inserted rows):

```
    @idUser int,
    @idRegion nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [UsersRegion] (idUser,IdRegion)
    VALUES (@idUser, @idRegion)
    SELECT @idUser,cast(value as int) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@idRegion,',')
END
```

I get this error when running it:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2,3,4' to data type int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending multiple values in @idRegion then when you split them, you may have more than 1 things you need to insert. Therefore, do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO [UsersRegion] (idUser,IdRegion)
SELECT @idUser, value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@idRegion, ',')
```

If the target table's `IdRegion` column is of type `int`, you need to cast like this:

```
SELECT @idUser, cast(value as int) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@idRegion, ',')
```

Above code will insert the same `@idUser` for every record but a different value for `IdRegion` depending the splitted items. More on [Insert into select from](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Comment: that looks good but i still get the same error when i try to manually type the string when executing the sp 

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2,3,4' to data type int.

Comment: @Dog If the table you are inserting into has an int column you need to cast: `SELECT @idUser, cast(value as int) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@idRegion, ',')`

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me, i am trying the following but i get an error in 'value', Invalid column name 'value'.

`SELECT @idUser, cast(value as int) FROM Viridis.dbo.Split(@idRegion,',')`

Comment: @Dog well what is `Viridis.dbo.Split(@idRegion,',')`? That is not what you had posted in your question. I thought you were using `STRING_SPLIT` function but now you are not. Try it with `STRING_SPLIT` and it will work.

Comment: even with CAST i get the same result

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2,3,4' to data type int.

Comment: @dog thats not possible and the error is about something else. Try this in SQL Mgmnt Studio all on its own and it will pass: `SELECT cast(value as int) FROM STRING_SPLIT('1,2,3,4,5', ',')` If that passes then your issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT statement seems to be working with `IdRegion` while everything else is lowercase `id`.

However, assuming this is how the actual table column is named and is not a typo...

Your problem is most likely the line that reads:
`@idRegion nvarchar(MAX)`
Which is declaring the @idRegion variable as a string, while you have stated in the question that it's meant to be an int.
This would explain the casting error.

If you cannot pass it into the procedure as an int from the C# code. Your only other option would be to try to parse it into an int as you have said.

Comment: Oh it's not a single number it's an array of numbers?  
All that I just said? That won't help you I'm afraid...    
CodingYoshi looks like he's on the right track.